# error con media Queries

Tags: html, css, headers

El problema es este, yo pongo el código en Css todo bien hasta que uso Media Queries yo puse que cuando la pantalla llegué a 450px cambie de display block a display none. Pero pasa nada, lo intente poniendo la etiqueta Meta viewport y tampoco pasa nada.

```css
{
  font-family: 'Lora', serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.responsive__li {
  display: none;
}

.nav {
  background-color: #6935EC;
}

.ul__li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
}

.ul__li:hover {
  color: #ccc;
}

.ul__li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.ul__li>a:hover {
  color: #ccc;
}

.ul__li i {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 5px;
}

@media only screen and (max-widht: 450px) {
  .nav-ul {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hola mirko, me parece que va a ser necesario que agregues tu html, para identificar el error, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta y lo agregues.
Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Answer (score 0):

Tienes mal escrita la propiedad, corrige 'max-widht' por 'max-width', no te preocupes me pasa a menudo los errores de teipeo, igual para los media queries, si quieres que se muestre a partir de un tamaños hacia uno mas grande la propiedad que puedes utilizar es 'min-width', entonces puedes tener una regla base 'display:block', y cuando sobrepase el query de min-width, pasarla a 'display:none'

Comment: muchas gracias, ahora si funciono